# MVC ViewModel - how to approach this requirement

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have what is (I'm sure)  quite a simple issue to fix, as it must be a common requirement. However, I'm new to this and can't seem to find the information that can help me work it out.

My Domain Model:

-Project (ID, ProjectName, Client)

Actor (ID, ProjectId, Title, Description)

On my CRUD for Actors I want to show Project Name as a readonly field (my application already knows which project I want to add actors to).

So, I need to create a view model which get's me the project name and all of my actors for that project. Here is what I have so far:

```
   public class ActorsViewModel
{
    //properties
    public string projectName {get; set;}
    public List<Actor> projectactors {get; set;}


    //constructor 
    public ActorsViewModel (int projectId)
    {
        //TODO
        /*
        project = //get the project name from the projects table
        projectActors = //get all of the actors for this project 

         */
    }
```

My aim is that on the index, the actors will be listed with their project name. In edit and create, the form will automatically be populated with the project name (and it will be readonly - I plan to do this by adding an attribute to the HTML Helper.

Can anyone give me some advice/point me in the right direction?

Comment: Are you asking how to fetch the actor and project name from your database that you didn't mention?

Comment: Logic to fetch data doesn't belong in your view model.

Comment: Are you really sure that an Actor can only have one project?

Comment: Yes I guess my first question is how my ViewModel should look - I wasn't sure whether I should just be bringing a project object and the related actor objects through or if I needed the properties, as I think I read somewhere that setting things like the data annotations should be done on the ViewModel

Comment: @mareinfinitus In this case that is correct - the application is for building use cases and the actors are specific to a client project

Answer (score 1):

This would need to go in your controller:

```
public ActionResult Edit(int projectId)
{
    using(var context = new CustomDbContext())
    {
        var model = new ActorsViewModel()
        {
            projectName = context.Projects.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Id = projectId).Name,
            projectactors = context.Actors.Where(a => a.ProjectId == projectId).ToList()
        }
    }

    return View(model);
}
```

Note that you would rather not create the context like this in your controller, but rather have it injected (or using a service or something). This is just to get you going, not showing best practices.

But you do want any logic in the Web project in your controller, not in your view model.

Comment: FirstOrDefault may return null, which in your code turns into a Null reference exception

Comment: @bump Thanks for this, it definitely gets me further along. So, in my ViewModel I just get a project object and the associated actor objects and I do the filtering to choose the project at the controller level (meaning the constructor of the ViewModel shouldn't take a parameter)?

Comment: @bump - any advice on what the model should look like? Thanks,

Comment: @gazrolo4 basically what you have now, but then an `IEnumerable{Actor}` instead of a `List`. You could consider using a view model for the `Actor` as well, since it is generally considered bad practice to use domain models (or data models in your case) as view models. So an `IEnumerable{ActorModel}` or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

To make sure the name can not be changed you may hide it in your viewmodel by removing the setter of the property and initialize the name during construction.

```
public class ActorsViewModel
{
    public ActorsViewModel(){} //Default ctor for modelbinder and co
    public ActorsViewModel(string projectName)
    {
        ProjectName = projectName;
    }
    public string ProjectName {get; }
    public List<Actor> ProjectActors {get; set;}
}
```

The disadvantage is that in your Post Controller Actions you need to either add the projectId/ProjectName to the request or look it up every time.